# Is there a fast way to return to the ground level on Tiny Tower?

Tags: tiny-tower

Is there a fast way to get to ground level on a Tiny Tower?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, the fastest way is to tap on the elevator arrows when they appear.  Other than that, you have to manually swipe until you reach the ground.  Side note: You can instantly go to the top by tapping on the top right bar that shows how many floors you have.

Answer (score 3):

Tap your coins, and it will automatically take you to the bottom. Tap the coins per second, and it will automatically take you to the top.

Answer (score 1):

Leave a small food floor at level two and don't stock it. You can jump to the exclamation point floor at any time.